# Execute a Program On Remote And Send Back Resulting File

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, freebsd, gcc

we have a powerful server to compile any code on it. For reasons, I am generally not allowed to copy my files to the server, and when I can, I can only use `/temp` which will be deleted after a reboot. And it gets really annoying having to copy files, compile the code and copy the output pack to my personal machine, only to get the files getting deleted on reboot.

Is it possible to send a request to the server (from my machine which has the files, example command: `gcc test.c -o output.file`) and redirect output back to my machine.

The server is running FreeBSD 12.1

Comment: I guess, something like `ssh yourserver gcc /dev/stdin -o /dev/stdout < local.test.c > local.output.file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might seems to be overengineering, but I would really recommend to use [Ansible](https://ansible.com). It is a really flexible tool and gives you a first step to "big" automation patterns.